# Grab LineNbr of Newly Inserted Line

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to get the line number of a newly inserted INTran row.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
INRegister issue = new INRegister();
//Code to populate INRegister...

INIssueEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INIssueEntry>();
graph.issue.Insert(issue);
graph.Actions.PressSave();

//PXSelect to get new RefNbr for INRegister object
issue = PXSelect<INRegister, Where<INRegister.refNbr, Equal<Current<INRegister.refNbr>>, 
    And<INRegister.docType, Equal<Current<INRegister.docType>>>>>.Select(graph);
graph.issue.Current = issue;

INTran issueRow = new INTran();
//Code to populate issueRow...

graph.transactions.Insert(issueRow);
graph.transactions.Current = issueRow;
graph.Actions.PressSave();
//Trying to get transaction line number
issueRow = PXSelect<INTran, Where<INTran.refNbr, Equal<Current<INTran.refNbr>>, 
    And<INTran.docType, Equal<Current<INTran.docType>>, 
    And<INTran.lineNbr, Equal<Current<INTran.lineNbr>>>>>>.Select(graph);

//At this point, issueRow is now null because LineNbr was null above
row.TranRefNbr = issueRow.RefNbr;
row.TranLineNbr = issueRow.LineNbr;
row.Released = true;
ItemReqs.Update(row);
//... ending code...
```

I've examined trying to save before setting as current (setting as current item for convenience for when I write the PXSelect to get the LineNbr), but I've found that the LineNbr, even on the graph, stays null during the entire excution. I've looked in the database as the graph is saving the new line and it does contain the line number. I'm not sure why my PXSelect isn't grabbing the line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert your transaction row the return should have the linenbr

```
var issueRow = graph.transactions.Insert(issueRow);
```

I am guessing your issue is that you are setting current after using the issueRow that was NOT returned which would have a null linenbr.

Also you really do not need to PressSave until the end (or ready to generate the batch) as the linenbr will still get set through the LineNbr attribute. Referring to a save after inserting the INRegister record.

I think current will also be set after you insert so I don't see a need to set current which will remove your need for the PXSelects.

Example getting the LineNbr in the simplest of steps:

```
INIssueEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INIssueEntry>();
graph.issue.Insert(new INRegister());
INTran issueRow = graph.transactions.Insert(new INTran());
//issueRow will now have a LineNbr value...
PXTrace.WriteInformation($"My Line Nbr is {issueRow.LineNbr}");
//RefNbr will receive its value when perform the Persist (Actions.PressSave)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I assume this works for reference numbers as well?

Comment: the transaction reference number will not work until you persist. The linenbr will work BEFORE persist. When you persist the ref number numbering sequence will get the next number.